# Numpy int32 самостоятельно изменяется на int64

Tags: python, numpy

При произведении какого-либо действия с переменной с  типом numpy.int32 тип меняется на numpy.int64, из-за чего я получаю неожиданные значения переменных.

Например, при побитовых операциях в результате получается не то число, которое мне требуется.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> (np.int32(335544318)<<6)>>4
1342177272
>>> type((np.int32(335544318)<<6)>>4)
<class 'numpy.int64'>
```

Если я не буду использовать numpy.int32, то все равно получу 1342177272:

```
>>> (335544318<<6)>>4
1342177272
```

Если сделать то же самое в JavaScript, то получится -8, которое мне как раз требовалось:

```
> (335544318<<6)>>4
< -8
```

Чтобы получить то же самое в Python, нужно после каждого действия вручную менять тип обратно на np.int32:

```
>>> np.int32(np.int32(335544318)<<6)>>4
-8
```

Я не могу понять, почему так происходит. Как мне заблокировать тип переменной, чтобы она сохраняла свои 32 бита?

Comment: какая у вас версия `numpy`?

Comment: Версия numpy 1.11.2, Python 3.5.2

Comment: в версии 1.11.1 `(np.int32(335544318)<<6)>>4` выдает `-8`

Comment: попробуйте так: `np.right_shift(np.left_shift(np.int32(335544318), 6), 4)`

Comment: Установил 1.11.1, и по какой-то причине оба варианта все равно приводят к 1342177272

Comment: интересный вопрос (для скаляров как на 1.8 так и на 1.11) типы меняются (integer promotion? implicit type conversion/coercion). Для массивов тип сохраняется: `np.array([335544318], dtype=np.int32).repeat(1000000) << 6 >> 4`

Comment: @MaxU а вы не на Windows случайно (там np.int_=long является 32 битным даже на 64 битной системе)? Тогда вопрос сводится к "почему `type(np.int32(0)+0)==np.int_`"

Comment: ещё интересней: [`type(np.uint64(0) + 0) == np.float64`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5745)

Comment: @jfs, действительно, я проверял на `Windows 64bit`. Но в моем случае: `type(np.int32(0)+0) == np.int32`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В NumPy используется [неявное приведение типов](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.result_type.html#numpy.result_type), похоже как это происходит в C/C++:

```
>>> np.result_type(np.int32(0), 0) 
dtype('int64') # np.int_
>>> np.result_type(np.int32(0), 1<<62)
dtype('int64')
>>> np.result_type(np.int32(0), 1<<63)
dtype('float64')
>>> np.result_type(np.int32(0), 1<<64)
dtype('O') # Python object
```

Чтобы узнать скалярный numpy тип, соответствующий заданному Python типу, можно использовать [`numpy.obj2sctype()` функцию](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.obj2sctype.html#numpy.obj2sctype). Для Python `int` используется [`numpy.int_` тип по умолчанию](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html):

```
>>> np.obj2sctype(int) == np.int_
True
```

Когда в выражении два скалярных типа, то [результат это наименьший тип, в который их можно преобразовать безопасно](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.promote_types.html#numpy.promote_types):

```
>>> np.promote_types(np.int32, np.int_) == np.int_
True
```

`np.int_` это обычно либо `np.int32` либо `np.int64` в зависимости от системы (C long):

- `np.int64` на 64-битной Linux (LP64 модель данных)
- [`np.int32` на 64-битной Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/storage-of-basic-types)